# Recycler Item Material transition not working correctly

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview, material-design, transition

I have a `RecyclerView` with populated items (`ImageView`, 2x `TextView`). On item click I start a new `Activity`. I want to use Material transition, where I want to re-arrange the `ImageView`.

Both `ImageViews` share the same transition name.

> **ISSUE:** When I press the Item, animation works and new activity starts with transition, but if I click items **which are below 1st item**,
>   the transition will **still start and end at the first row**.

```
@Override
public void openUserDetails(UiBaseUser data, View view, int position) {
    iwAvatar = ButterKnife.findById(this, R.id.iw_avatar);

    Pair<View, String> p1 = Pair.create(iwAvatar, "avatar");
    ActivityOptionsCompat optionsCompat = ActivityOptionsCompat
            .makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, p1);
    startActivity(UserDetailActivity.getIntent(getApplicationContext(), data), optionsCompat.toBundle());
}
```

The above code is executed in `SourceActivity` and does not have direct link to `item_list` `XML` layout. That is why I use `Butterknife` there, to find the `ImageView` that I want to animate - however, this seems to only grab the first element `ImageView` and not the `ImageView` that was actually pressed.

Here is my `adapter class` (I assume I am missing something here out). In this ViewHolder class I have reference to the layout `UserListLayout` (`item_list`) where `ImageView` is located.

```
public class UsersAdapter extends BaseAdapter<UiBaseUser, UsersAdapter.UserVH> {

    private final LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public UsersAdapter(Context context) {
        this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public UserVH onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new UserVH(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_users, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(UsersAdapter.UserVH holder, int position) {
        ViewCompat.setTransitionName(holder.layout.getIwAvatar(), "image_view_" + position);
        holder.onBind(getItem(position));
    }

    public class UserVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private UserListLayout layout;

        public UserVH(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            layout = (UserListLayout) itemView;
        }

        public void onBind(UiBaseUser item) {
            layout.bind(item);
        }

    }
}
```

**TargetActivity snippet**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_detail);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    initializeDagger();

    bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (bundle != null) {
        transitionName = bundle.getString(EXTRA_TRANSITION_NAME);
        presenter.onCreate(baseData);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Initial bundle in UserDetail Activity is null");
    }

    iwAvatar.setTransitionName(transitionName);    
}
```

I feel like I am missing something simple out - but straight hours of coding exhausted my brains well enough, to not see it through. Please help me out.

Comment: You're changing the transition name of the list items, but there's nothing in your sample that would indicate the same for the target `Activity`'s view.

Comment: I added target activity on create snippet, to show how I set the transition name through Bundle. I did not want to put all of the code here, because people usually ignore longer posts.

Comment: Did you check if `transitionName` contains the expected value with the correct position index in your target `Activity` (I guess it's `UserDetailActivity`)?

Comment: It does. This works perfectly fine, if I isolate my RecyclerClickListener only to ImageView (iw.setOnItemClickListener()), however in that case, if user presses somewhere else in the row, nothing happens. If presses on ImageView the transition works as it should. But I want that transition works even if user presses TextView (still Imageview should animate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lays in the click handler (`openUserDetails(...)` does that if I'm correct).

`iwAvatar = ButterKnife.findById(this, R.id.iw_avatar);` is not gonna work here because you have multiple views with the same ID `R.id.iw_avatar` in your layout. You can do the following to find the correct `ImageView` instance:

1. Pass the selected view (*possibly your `itemView` in `UserVH`*) to `openUserDetails(...)` (*I guess you do that now too*)
2. Call `findViewById(...)` on this `view` param to find the actual `ImageView`.

Comment: Sounds like it could work, will test and let you know. Thanks for suggestion!

Comment: I have created an interface between activity and adapter and listened for onClickEvents inside adapter, where I coudl getAdapterPosition() on item and then searched for ImageView inside the ViewHolder.  Your answer led me to this so I accept it. Thanks again!